# Wait for signal while processing other signals

Tags: c++, qt

My Qt application talks to a serial device, and occasionally has to wait for this device to send a byte. To accomplish this, I create a new eventloop that exits as soon as there is information available in the serial buffer:

```
unsigned char MyClass::waitForDevice(int timeout)
{
    QEventLoop wait;
    connect(d_serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), &wait, SLOT(quit()));
    if (timeout > 0)
        QTimer::singleShot(timeout, &wait, SLOT(quit()));

    wait.exec();
    return static_cast<unsigned char>(d_serial->read(1)[0]);
}
```

Now the problem is that, while the application is waiting, i.e. while the eventloop is running, I need to be able to communicate to the serial device when a button is pressed in the GUI. Naively, I tried connecting a signal to a slot that does this, but I found that the slot is only executed *after* the eventloop is terminated.

I tried, without any luck, to have a seperate QThread running that calls `qApp->processEvents()` in an infinite loop, which is terminated when the eventloop is terminated. This didn't work, and I'm not quite sure why not. What is the canonical way to resolve this?

Comment: Solution: Only do reading in a slot, which gets called by `readyRead()` signal. And never block the event loop, so you can't have a `waitForXxxx` method like that. Instead, connect the signals to slots, and do things in the slots. Never block. If you seem to need to block, at that point you need to `return`, and then continue when you get the right signal.

Comment: local event loops and processEvents() lead into a world of pain, I can only recommend not to use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're thinking synchronously in a pre-C++1z world. In C++14 (and prior) asynchronous programming, there is mostly no place for a notion of a `wait` that is implemented as a function that returns when the wait is over (`switch`-based [coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/coroutine.html) [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10842585/1329652) [excepted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7213839/1329652)). You are also not using the fact that your application is stateful, and the state transitions can be expressed in a state machine.

Instead, you should simply act on data being available. Presumably, your application can be in multiple states. One of the states - the one where you have to wait for input - is simply exited when the input arrives.

The example below uses a simple process-local pipe, but it would work exactly the same if you were using a serial port - both are a `QIODevice` and emit requisite signals. We start with the project file.

```
# async-comms-32309737.pro
QT       += widgets core-private
TARGET = async-comms-32309737
CONFIG   += c++11
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

To make things simple, the pipe implementation reuses the `QRingBuffer` private class from Qt. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32317081/1329652) for more fleshed-out implementation(s).

```
// main.cpp
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <private/qringbuffer_p.h>

/// A simple point-to-point intra-application pipe. This class is not thread-safe.
class AppPipe : public QIODevice {
   Q_OBJECT
   AppPipe * m_other { nullptr };
   QRingBuffer m_buf;
public:
   AppPipe(AppPipe * other, QObject * parent = 0) : QIODevice(parent), m_other(other) {
      open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
   }
   void setOther(AppPipe * other) { m_other = other; }
   qint64 writeData(const char * data, qint64 maxSize) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
      if (!maxSize) return maxSize;
      m_other->m_buf.append(QByteArray(data, maxSize));
      emit m_other->readyRead();
      return maxSize;
   }
   qint64 readData(char * data, qint64 maxLength) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
      return m_buf.read(data, maxLength);
   }
   qint64 bytesAvailable() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
      return m_buf.size() + QIODevice::bytesAvailable();
   }
   bool isSequential() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE { return true; }
};
```

We start with a simple UI, with one button to restart the state machine, another to transmit a single byte that will be received by the client, and a label that indicates the current state of the state machine.

[image: screenshot of the example]

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a { argc, argv };
   QWidget ui;
   QGridLayout grid { &ui };
   QLabel state;
   QPushButton restart { "Restart" }, transmit { "Transmit" };
   grid.addWidget(&state, 0, 0, 1, 2);
   grid.addWidget(&restart, 1, 0);
   grid.addWidget(&transmit, 1, 1);
   ui.show();
```

We now create the simulated device and the client pipe endpoints.

```
   AppPipe device { nullptr };
   AppPipe client { &device };
   device.setOther(&client);
```

The state machine has three states. The `s_init` is the initial state, and is exited after a 1.5s delay. The `s_wait` state is only exited when we receive some data (a byte or more) from the device *in that state*. In this example, receiving the data in other states has no effect. The machine is set to restart automatically when stopped.

```
   QStateMachine sm;
   QState
         s_init { &sm },    // Exited after a delay
         s_wait { &sm },    // Waits for data to arrive
         s_end { &sm };     // Final state
   QTimer timer;
   timer.setSingleShot(true);

   sm.setInitialState(&s_init);
   QObject::connect(&sm, &QStateMachine::stopped, &sm, &QStateMachine::start);
   QObject::connect(&s_init, &QState::entered, [&]{ timer.start(1500); });
   s_init.addTransition(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &s_wait);
   s_wait.addTransition(&client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), &s_end);
```

To visualize the state machine's progress, we assign the `state` label's `text` property in each of the states:

```
   s_init.assignProperty(&state, "text", "Waiting for timeout.");
   s_wait.assignProperty(&state, "text", "Waiting for data.");
   s_end.assignProperty(&state, "text", "Done.");
```

Finally, the `restart` button stops the state machine - it will self-restart then. The `transmit` button simulates the device sending one byte of data.

```
   QObject::connect(&restart, &QPushButton::clicked, &sm, &QStateMachine::stop);
   QObject::connect(&transmit, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]{
      device.write("*", 1);
   });
```

We start the machine, enter the event loop, and let Qt follow our directions onwards from here. The `main.moc` file is included for it contains the metadata for `AppPipe`.

```
   sm.start();
   return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a detailed answer. It seems I have to rethink a bit more of the application. I did not quite understand though what you meant in your opening paragraph. What is it about this approach that makes it so C++11/14 (aside from the lambda's)?

Comment: @JorenHeit What I mean is that this approach is specifically **pre**-C++14. In C++14, you can write synchronous-looking code, if doing so is convenient, while still producing behavior that yields control away from the function and retains its state. Qt lacks integration with it, though, because there is at the moment IIRC one (1) compiler that can deal with it and that's about it.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with C++14 but I have no idea what you are talking about... could you be more specific? What features are you referring to?

Comment: @JorenHeit Stackless and stackful `yield` is supposed to be possible in C++14, right? With that, you can write code that has the syntax of Basic and expressiveness of, well, C++14 :)

Comment: Aaaaah I thought that would be it, but AFAK that's a proposed feature for C++1y. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JorenHeit Yeah, I'm wrong. It's a proposed feature for C++ 1z I guess, since 1x was 11, 1y was 14...

Comment: Whoops, typo. Yes that's what I meant. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

There are several Types of which Signals and Slots can be connected.

See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum

Have you tried **Qt::DirectConnection**: `connect(d_serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), &wait, SLOT(quit()),Qt::DirectConnection);` ?

Comment: The direct connection is implied if the objects live in the same thread, so the last argument is unnecessary. If you are trying it with objects in different threads, then the target slot must be thread-safe. Generally speaking, there are few uses for explicit direct connections - normally they'd be used when invoking thread-safe slots in objects that run in threads without an event loop, or when invoking thread-safe slots to pre-empt any events in the target thread's event loop.

Comment: Ok, that sounds logical. @Kuba